# How to Insulate Drop Ceiling Above Tiled Shower?

Tags: insulation, shower, ceiling, attic, vapor-barrier

First post so bear with me...

I am working on air sealing for my 1965 ranch style home in NJ, and noticed that the insulation in the attic above the tiled shower is black and brittle (kraft paper) and falling apart.  I want to remove the existing R-12 and add a significant increase in R value but not sure how to do it without creating a moisture sandwich?

I was debating between adding polyiso/Rmax sheets over the area in the attic and sealing them, or just stuffing unfaced batts all around the enclosure and trying to seal above with jointed and caulked plywood to also serve as an attic deck.

I can't really find any recommendations online after a few hours of searching...   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you working with a vented attic, or an unvented (cathedralized) attic?

Comment: It is a vented attic. Batts are stuffed up against the soffit but that's a seperate issue that I will fix in the spring.